# load Database function doesn't return Codelgniter mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I can't connect to mysql database 
whatever I use

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

or

```
 $this->load->database();
```

function hangs and never returns

here is my database configurations

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'root';
$db['default']['database'] = 'sms_web';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

What shall i do ??

Solved 
Thanks for you efforts

```
PHP wasn't configured correctly with mysql
```

Comment: Is your database started ?

Comment: Yes, I am connected to it using workbench

Comment: Just keep the autoload config. I don't see anything wrong in it. I guess you've checked the usual: host, port, user, password and db ?

Comment: did it, but even if they are wrong should not  $this->load->database(); returns error ??

Comment: when i use autoload, even the welcome page is not loaded

Answer (score 0):

PHP.ini file has commented loading mysql extension 
just i made sure of the configuration of PHP